# Lambda automatically deletes transcribe job upon completion

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.7, amazon-transcribe

I am looking to edit my lambda so it will delete the transcription job when it's job status reads "Complete". I have the following code:

```
 import json
    import time
    import boto3
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        transcribe = boto3.client("transcribe")
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")

        if event:
            file_obj = event["Records"][0]
            bucket_name = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
            file_name = str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"])
            s3_uri = create_uri(bucket_name, file_name)
            file_type = file_name.split("2019.")[1]
            job_name = file_name
            transcribe.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name,
                                                Media ={"MediaFileUri": s3_uri},
                                                MediaFormat = file_type,
                                                LanguageCode = "en-US",
                                                Settings={
                                                    "VocabularyName": "Custom_Vocabulary_by_Brand_Other_Brands",
                                                    "ShowSpeakerLabels": True,
                                                    "MaxSpeakerLabels": 4
                                                })


            while True:
                status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
                if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["FAILED"]:
                    break
                print("It's in progress")
            while True:
                status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
                if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["COMPLETED"]:
                    transcribe.delete_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name
                )

                time.sleep(5)

            load_url = urlopen(status["TranscriptionJob"]["Transcript"]["TranscriptFileUri"])
            load_json = json.dumps(json.load(load_url))

            s3.put_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = "transcribeFile/{}.json".format(job_name), Body=load_json)


        # TODO implement
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
        }

    def create_uri(bucket_name, file_name):
        return "s3://"+bucket_name+"/"+file_name
```

The section that handles the job is:

```
 while True:
        status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
        if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["FAILED"]:
            break
        print("It's in progress")
    while True:
        status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
        if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["COMPLETED"]:
            transcribe.delete_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name
        )
```

If the job is in progress, it will say "It's in progress", but when it reads "Completed" it will delete.

Any ideas why my current code would not be working? It completes the transcribe job but does not delete it.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), will help to get an answer.

Comment: @jarmod Apologies, I will amend my original question. The current code does not delete the jobs. It simply completes it as normal and does nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I had another look and made a very very stupid mistake. I had the `transcribe.delete_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name` in the complete incorrect part.

Please find the correct and working code below:

```
import json
import time
import boto3
from urllib.request import urlopen

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    transcribe = boto3.client("transcribe")
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucket_name = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        file_name = str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"])
       s3_uri = create_uri(bucket_name, file_name)
        file_type = file_name.split("2019.")[1]
        job_name = file_name
        transcribe.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name,
                                            Media ={"MediaFileUri": s3_uri},
                                            MediaFormat = file_type,
                                            LanguageCode = "en-US",
                                            Settings={
                                                "VocabularyName": "Custom_Vocabulary_by_Brand_Other_Brands",
                                                "ShowSpeakerLabels": True,
                                                "MaxSpeakerLabels": 4
                                            })


        while True:
            status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
            if status["TranscriptionJob"]["TranscriptionJobStatus"] in ["COMPLETED", "FAILED"]:
                transcribe.delete_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
                break
            print("It's in progress")

            time.sleep(5)

        load_url = urlopen(status["TranscriptionJob"]["Transcript"]["TranscriptFileUri"])
        load_json = json.dumps(json.load(load_url))

        s3.put_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = "transcribeFile/{}.json".format(job_name), Body=load_json)


    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }

def create_uri(bucket_name, file_name):
    return "s3://"+bucket_name+"/"+file_name
```

Comment: While this might work, it's not optimal. Specifically, it's fragile (it will fail if Lambda times out before a job reaches the desired state) and wasteful (it's mostly sleeping rather than doing anything useful, so costs more than it should). You can completely automate the transitions you want in a simple, optimal fashion using event-based solution based on CloudWatch Events and Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You should not poll for information if you can avoid it, *especially* in Lambda.

The correct way to respond to changes in transcription job status is to [use CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/cloud-watch-events.html). You can, for example, configure a rule to route an event to an AWS Lambda function when a transcription job has completed successfully.

When your Lambda function is invoked as a result of a status change in the transcription job, the Lambda function will receive `event` data, for example:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "1a234567-1a6d-3ab4-1234-abf8b19be1234",
    "detail-type": "Transcribe Job State Change",
    "source": "aws.transcribe",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2019-11-19T10:00:05Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "TranscriptionJobName": "my-transcribe-test",
        "TranscriptionJobStatus": "COMPLETED"
    }
}
```

Use the `TranscriptionJobName` to correlate the state change back to the original job.

Comment: except that it doesn't give you the name of the job that's completed, just the id that doesn't even come back when you request a list of jobs.

Comment: @StevenGrant the docs indicate that the Transcribe Event has a `detail` attribute with both `TranscriptionJobName` and `TranscriptionJobStatus`, per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/cloud-watch-events.html#events. The `id` is just a CloudWatch identifier.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately `detail` comes back as null, not even the `TranscriptionJobName` or `TranscriptionJobStatus` exists in there

Comment: @StevenGrant Did you test this and found `detail` to be empty? It worked correctly for me (multiple times) in us-east-1. Have included an example of the event data in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I did - the docs suggest detail should contain job status and job name but it's just null. Someone did suggest input transformer but no dice on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938814/cloudwatch-events-trigger-on-amazon-transcribe-event

Comment: @StevenGrant I’d consider raising a support case with the details of the transcribe job name, the CW event ID, and the full CW event data so AWS can look into it. The docs are pretty clear and it does work fine, at least in my experience.