# CloudWatch Events trigger on Amazon Transcribe event

Tags: events, aws-lambda, jobs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-transcribe

I'm working with the Amazon Transcribe service and trying to get CloudWatch Events to fire a Lambda function that executes a POST request to my API.

Here's the Lambda function

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


    var post_data = querystring.stringify(
        event
    );

    // An object of options to indicate where to post to
    var post_options = {
        host: '193e561e.ngrok.io',
        port: '80',
        path: '/api/lambda',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

    // Set up the request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
            context.succeed();
        });
        res.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
        });

    });

    // post the data
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();

}
```

I've configured CloudWatch Events to listen to the Amazon Transcribe service and specifically for the status of a job changing to `COMPLETED` or `FAILED`.

[image: cloudwatch event trigger]

What's surprising however is that there's no mention of the Transcribe job name in that event response.

Here's an example:

```
'version' => '0',
  'id' => '1fa5cca6-413f-4a0f-0ba2-66efa49c247e',
  'detail-type' => 'Transcribe Job State Change',
  'source' => 'aws.transcribe',
  'account' => '405723091079',
  'time' => '2019-11-19T19:04:25Z',
  'region' => 'eu-west-1',
  'detail' => NULL,
```

This is the only way I can think of my app working where the transcription job is invoked via the Amazon Transcribe service and then when it's done, hit my API to update the necessary models in my app but without getting the Transcribe job name, it won't work.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `detail` is supposed to return the job status and the job name but is always null :(

Comment: In other events I have had to add details in the Input Transformer, which is in configure event under in add target. You are probably looking to add something like {"TranscriptionJobName": "$.detail.TranscriptionJobName"}, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax for Transcribe.

Comment: Assuming it follows the cli reference, try adding {"TranscriptionJobName": "$.detail.transcription-job-name"} in the Input Transformer.

Comment: Have you done that via the GUI or only using the cli?

Comment: I haven't done either, but the instructions (which are best guess) are for the gui

Comment: Yeah, gave them a whirl but each time the request was empty. It seems like the whole event should be just fine.

Comment: How are you acquiring that response? Asking in case whatever method you are using is what is hiding the detail.  I just ran a quick test by targeting the event to an SNS topic that emailed it to me, and I do see a valid detail block.

Comment: A similar question might be how are you creating the job?  While it shouldn't matter, you might try creating a simple test job using the AWS console to see if you get the same result.  Also fyi, the detail I receive does include the job name, as per the docs.

Comment: @kaliatech have updated the question with the actual Lambda function and the CloudWatch event trigger.

Comment: steven did u find the solution?

Comment: @kaliatech would u give me the official docs link where SNS topic is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your updated question, I suspect your issue is actually here:

```
var post_data = querystring.stringify(
    event
);
```

Querystring does not support nested objects, such as the `detail` block of the cloudwatch event. More info:

- https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#user-content-nesting

So although you didn't indicate it in your question, I suspect you are showing the response that you are receiving as the result of this lambda post, not the raw response/event you are receiving from AWS Transcribe.

Perhaps instead of querystring:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify(event);
```

Comment: good spot, a little bit of a difference in output but still missing the detail `[2019-11-20 17:35:54] local.INFO: array (
  '{"version":"0","id":"471dd01a-b38e-6334-a9a5-2b1a63078f92","detail-type":"Transcribe_Job_State_Change","source":"aws_transcribe","account":"405723091079","time":"2019-11-20T17:35:53Z","region":"eu-west-1","resources":' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
  ),
) `

Comment: OK - was indeed the Lambda function at fault. Here's the updated Lambda function working https://gist.github.com/1stevengrant/e7a3e0313f7a40c74013fd5194e4e738 - will accept your answer as it set me on the right track :) Thank you.